# Stack Overflow Enterprise API support

Tags: support, api, so-enterprise

Does Stack Overflow Enterprise support REST API?

If so, where could I find the docs?

If not, will it be supported in the near future?

Comment: Just in case you missed it, answer was edited and API is live.

Answer (score 11):

The Stack Overflow Enterprise offers an API that is currently in Beta with several customers.

In its initial form, the API is quite similar to the publicly available [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/), but only with read-only abilities.

If your company has Stack Overflow Enterprise, but has not yet adopted the API, feel free to reach out to your admin to request it. We're happy to set it up for additional customers.

If you would like to learn more about Stack Overflow Enterprise, feel free to request more info [here](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise).

Comment: It's second quarter of 2017 now. Any news on the Enterprise API? Thanks

Comment: @SashaO thanks for your patience on my response. I have gone ahead and updated my answer.

Comment: @ChanceHeath is there a roadmap for this API? Specifically, write functionality?