# Is there a way to publish a question for a team within a public stack?

Tags: support, questions, so-enterprise, stack-overflow-for-teams

My company has a public StackExchange for customers but I wonder if it would be possible to post questions within the same stack and somehow mark it just for the internal team to answer and view it.

Is there any way of publishing internal questions for specific teams within a public StackExchange?

Thanks

Comment: I wasn't aware that SE had a way to have 'public' hosted SE instances outside the SE network umbrella for individual organisations.

Comment: I don't expect there will be anything out of the box, given this question and its answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331806/can-i-use-the-stack-exchange-app-to-connect-to-our-companys-private-stack-overf

Comment: There is also this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286827/stack-overflow-enterprise-api-support but that still requires you to build something.

Comment: I think that this would be something to take up with the SE representative assigned to your company.

Comment: The answers published here are not even closed to what I'm looking for, I don't know because maybe I don't understand the relationship or because I didn't explain myself correctly so I will give an example.

Imagine we have: https://askubuntu.com/ and customers of ubuntu ask questions there but the team who is developing ubuntu would like to have internal questions about processes without having to rent a new stack. is it possible for this dev team to publish private questions inside, just available for the dev team?

Please, let me know if I'm not explaining myself correctly

Comment: You should ask the company itself, use the contact information at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Mrquestion You can add Teams on top of Enterprise, so if you have a fully fledged Enterprise instance that y'all grant access to clients, by adding Teams to Enterprise you should be able to do both but, as others have stated, the best solution is to talk to your Enterprise Customer Success representative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't have private posts or posts that are only actionable for a specific user/group of users on a public StackExchange site, say AskUbuntu.com.

You either need a subscription for [SO for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) (note that the teams option only exist under Stack Overflow) or get a license for [SO Enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise) (but that is only beneficial if you have lots of private users and enough money to burn).

If you already have an Enterprise instance you can add Teams on top of it. That would give you private teams within your own Enterprise instance. Your Enterprise Customer Success representative knows the details about this option and can assist in enabling this for you.

Both Teams and Enterprise have some limited ways to interact with it by the use of an API, and/or Slack integration, allowing for internal routing of questions.