# Is there a way to subscribe to questions asked by members of a "private" Stack Overflow on the "public" Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, linked-accounts, subscription, association, stack-overflow-for-teams

My company has a "private" Stack Overflow space. But my company members often have general questions that they ask on the "public" Stack Overflow, because they don't concern company-specific subjects.

I would like to help my company members by answering their questions both on the public and private Stack Overflow. Is it possible to "subscribe" to questions my company members asked on the public Stack Overflow?

I would create a "feature-request" tagged question if there is no way to achieve it. But first, I would like to know if someone achieved it in some way.

Comment: There's an entire chain of duplicate questions in the linked duplicate - essentially, you can use an RSS feed to follow someone's activity but we don't have any sort of way to do it built into the site. Getting automatic notifications for new content created by someone can often lead to issues like targeted voting, which is very problematic for our system. :) While this isn't an issue for Teams - since we don't have policies about how to vote on a team, it's certainly something you could request as part of a Teams improvement.

Comment: You could subscribe to their RSS feeds:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/1044638

Comment: @Catija I saw questions pointed as "duplicates" but they didn't answer my question. Thanks for highlighting the targeted voting issue, I haven't thought about that and it's probably the reason "why I can't subscribe people" that links my question with the chain of duplicates.

Comment: @rene I'm unable to maintain subscriptions of thousands of people in my company.

Comment: Go work for a small startup ;) ... but yeah, subscribing to 1000 users is probably a bit much ...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350317/is-there-a-way-to-publish-a-question-for-a-team-within-a-public-stack (opposite direction).